# Unable to run subprocess and also redirecting output to a log file

Tags: python

The following code does not write into the log file which I am creating ('Dm_Log.txt'). But if I comment out `stdout,stderr = process.communicate()` then it does. If I do not use `communicate()`, subprocess stalls since I am doing `process.wait()`. How to resolve this? I need to write in the log file and run the process too.

```
logfilePath = self.psexeclogs + 'Dm_Log.txt'
logfile = file(logfilePath, 'w')

try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(drivemaster_open_command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    for line in process.stderr:
        print ' '
        sys.stderr.write(line)
        logfile.write(line)
    process.wait()

except OSError:
    print "********COULD NOT FIND PSEXEC.EXE, PLEASE REINSTALL AND SET THE PATH VARIABLE PROPERLY********\n"

# Close the logfile first
logfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

After you use `communicate` as it **wait for process to terminate**, then you cannot use `process.stderr` instead you just can use `stderr`.

> [**Popen.communicate(input=None)**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)
>
> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate

```
for line in stderr:
   print ' '
   sys.stderr.write(line)
   logfile.write(line)
```